# InDesign spreads export to PDF viewable as spreads but printable only as single pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I have a 12 page brochure set up in InDesign as spreads.
I want to export the design as a PDF viewable as spreads but printable only as single pages.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Export the PDF as single pages.

Then in Acrobat, set the PDF **View Options** to display `Two-Page View`

[image]

This changes how the current PDF is displayed. But it does **not** alter how the PDF will be displayed the next time it is opened.

---

If you want *everyone* to always see two page spreads when opening the PDF, then use `File > Properties` to set the `Initial View > Page Display` to "Two-Up" (with or without a cover) and **save** the file.

[image]

If you select "Cover Page" it means page 1 will always display as a single page, then pages from pg2 onward will be displayed in pairs. "Continuous" means the pages display as a long scrollable strip (in pairs) as opposed to needing to hit a "turn" page button or arrow key to see the next set of pages.

---

All this merely changes how the PDF is **displayed**. It does **not** alter how the PDF is printed. The PDF will still *print* single pages even though it shows two pages on screen.

---

<sup>These are Acrobat X screenshots. It is not impossible that Adobe has improved things a bit in the last few years. 

Menus and windows may look slightly different or be located in a slightly different locations in newer versions of Acrobat.</sup>

---

As far as I'm aware, you can **not** set these types of PDF display options from within InDesign's PDF export for *print* PDFs. PDF display options for print PDFs *must* be set from within Acrobat. Exporting to an *Interactive* PDF using InDesign *will* show page display options in the export dialog. (All of this is as of CC2019/CS6 - It may have changed in 2020+ versions)

Comment: Actually, you *can* setup the viewing options when exporting a PDF from InDesign. For an *Interactive PDF* it works as expected with all layout options. For some reason unknown to me, *Two-Up (Facing)* and *Two-Up (Cover Page)* are grayed out when exporting a *Print PDF*, so I sometimes end up doing like you propose here.

Comment: @Wolff Must be a newer development - Admittedly I *prefer* legacy versions of the app and avoid CC, *especially* Acrobat DC. -- In Indesign CS6, there's no option to alter the Initial View options of a (print) PDF. There are page display options for an Interactive PDF. Not certain if this user can use an Interactive PDF.. I just assumed print since the question references printing.

Comment: It works fine for print PDFs as well in recent versions of InDesign (not sure when exactly it was added – CC something). @Wolff, those settings require a newer version of PDF than the others, so if you’re exporting based on PDF-X or PDF/A-1 (or some of the other standards whose names all blur together for me), then they’re not available. Choose PDF 7 and they become selectable.